# User select one annotation on MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotationview

I do a app with MapKit and I want the user can select an annotation (clic on) and then open a new view controller.
I do it with the method :

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showClic", sender: nil)
}
```

But this code open the VC when there a cluster of annotation.
And I want to do when there is a cluster of annotation a zoom with the camera and open the VC only when only one annotation is selected.

Answer (score 0):

func fitMapViewToAnnotaionList(annotations: [MKPointAnnotation], userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void {
let mapEdgePadding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
var zoomRect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectNull

```
    for index in 0..<annotations.count {
        let annotation = annotations[index]
        let aPoint:MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
        let rect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectMake(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)

        if MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect) {
            zoomRect = rect
        } else {
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, rect)
        }
    }

    let aPoint:MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(userLocation)
    let rect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectMake(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)

    if MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect) {
        zoomRect = rect
    } else {
        zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, rect)
    }
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: mapEdgePadding, animated: true)
}
```